# How to access to google checkout in adobe air?

Tags: android, air, google-checkout

I need to write application for Android using Adobe AIR. And I need to sell some goods. For this purpose I want to use google checkout, how can I use it from Adobe AIR? Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google checkout isn't accessible from Air applications, there are only SDKs for
Java, .NET, PHP and other languages accept Action Script 3.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html